# Looping to assign list of lists into arrays

Tags: python, arrays, list, loops, numpy

I have a list of lists and I want to assign each of the sublists to an array of shape a particular shape. So far I have:

```
N=23

# read the file in lines
with open('ircforward.xyz','r') as f:
    lines = f.read().splitlines()

# Split the whole file into a list of lists 
profiles = [lines[i:i + N] for i in xrange(0, len(lines), N)]

#Convert first sublist to array skipping the first two lines    
set1 = np.genfromtxt(profiles[0],skip_header=2,usecols=[1,2,3])
```

Is there a way I can generate a bunch of arrays named "set_n" where n would be an indexing variable and have something along the lines of:

```
for n in range (4000):
      set_n = np.genfromtxt(profile[n], skip_header=2, usecols=[1,2,3])
```

Comment: Rather than having `set_1`, `set_2`, etc, just build an array-of-sets: `sets[n] = np.genfromtxt(...)`. Or a dict-of-sets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best solution is to use a dictionary as follows:

```
my_dict = {}

for n in range (4000):
      my_dict['set_{}'.format(n)] = np.genfromtxt(profile[n], skip_header=2, usecols=[1,2,3])
```

Now, instead of using `set_1`, `set_2`, etc you can use `my_dict['set_1']`, `my_dict['set_2']`, etc

Comment: Will I still be able to call specific elements of the arrays? For example if I want to assign the first value of the second row in set1 to a variable can I do something like x = set_1[1,0]

Comment: You can do `x = my_dict['set_1'][1,0]`

Comment: Is it then possible to do variable assignment through the dictionary as a loop something along the lines of:
for n in range (4000):
'x'.format(n) = my_dict['set_{}'.format(n)][1,0]

Comment: You can't create variables that way, that's why we used a dictionary to solve the same issue above. Instead, you can read one item like `x_1 = my_dict['set_1'][1,0]`